# My bot is responding to all prefixes and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am using the latest node.js and discord.js versions and I am coding on VSC.
My bot started responding to all prefixes and I don't know why. The code I have currently:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
 
const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file }`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command)
}

const PREFIX = '$';
 
 
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('updated');
})

client.on('message', message => {
 
    const args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'ping':
            message.channel.send('pong!');
            break;
    }
});
 
        client.login(token);
```

However, with this code in mind, the bot still responds to any prefix. In the image below, I sent the ping command with various random letters and symbols in all at the same time. The bot responded pong to all of them.

[image: Image of the bot not working]

not sure what is wrong as I am still new to discord.js but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can check if it's a command before.

```
client.on('message', message => {
  
  const isCommand = message.content.substring(0,PREFIX.length) === PREFIX
  if(isCommand){
    const args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'ping':
            message.channel.send('pong!');
            break;
    }
  }
});
```